# Using WMIC to return hostnames with specific product installed

Tags: wmic

I'm trying to use WMIC to query remote computers to discover which ones have a particular product installed.

For example the query I'm running looks like:

```
wmic:root\cli>/node:@HOSTNAMES.txt /output:INSTALLS.txt product where "name like 'APPNAME&'" get name,version
```

While this returns the application information I need, it doesn't break it down by host name.

Anyone know if there is there a way to get this information using WMIC or should I try using something else?